# Socket Programming in C, need to create one socket which can communicate with two ports of hich one is secure and other is unsecure

Tags: sockets

Need help with socket Programming. Can some one please help.

Need to develop one application (like Application A) having single socket and it  communicates with two other applications(like Application B and Application C) using socket running on different port.

The Application B is having secure port and it works on TLS protocol. While Application C is having unsecure port and it works on TCP protocol.

So it is possible that Application A having single socket running on TCP protocol can communicate with other two application ( B and C) running on different port and protocols.

Request to please help. If it's possible then how can it be done.

Comment: The answer is likely yes, but you're question isn't well formed.  Which applications are the server and which ones are the client?  What is the order of connections and who initiates each?

Comment: It is like Application B is a client , Application A is running on server and Application C is running on some other server.   So it will be like  Application B------>Application A-----> Application C

Comment: The short answer is yes. Your application A has a listening socket hooked up to (Open)SLL.  When A connects to C, it can re-use the local client port, although it's completely unnecessary for it to do so.  Regardless of which port A uses to connect to C, there's no requirement that it uses TLS/SSL for its outbound connections even though it's required for inbound.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your help. If possible can you share some link as I am new to socket programming. And i need to develop this in C technology without using Openssl

Comment: You can't develop secure socket code without OpenSSL or an equivalent library.  It would be foolish, and a waste of time to try to reinvent it.  (Exception: There's an equivalent crypto API in Win32 that can be used with Winsock). Or worse, you invent your own encryption - not a good idea.  In any case, the best starting point for learning sockets is [Beej's Guide to Network Programming](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/)

Comment: Ok.. Can i use schannel for doing this

Comment: Or any microsoft api that can be used to do so

Comment: Yes, schannel is the API I was thinking of.